# Как при создании нового fxml окна изменить значение существующего поля

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Проблема вот в чем:
Есть метод, создающий окно ошибки, в  котором значение текстового поля должно стать равным Message.
Дело в том, что я не знаю, как изменить значение уже существующего поля. 
[image]
[Шаблон окна ошибки, генерируя который при возникновении какой-нибудь ошибки, я бы смогла заменять значение label на свой текст].

Сам метод без вызова метода SetMessage:

```
private void issueAnErrorMessage(String Message)
    {

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/sample/Error page.fxml"));
        try
        {
            loader.load();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Parent root = loader.getRoot();
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.showAndWait();
    }
```

Класс окна ошибки:

```
  public class  ErrorPage
{
    @FXML
    private ResourceBundle resources;

    @FXML
    private URL location;

    @FXML
    private Label errorText;

    @FXML
    private Button OkeyBut;

    @FXML
    void initialize()
    {

    }


     public void SetMessage( String message)
    {
        //System.out.println(errorText.getTextFill());
        errorText.setText(message);
    }
    }
```

Что нужно сделать в методе issueAnErrorMessage() и SetMessage () - ума не приложу :с 
Может можно как-то использовать ResourceBundle resources и URL location? 
Подскажите, кто что знает, как реализовать данную задачу. Заранее спасибо за помощь c:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш класс ErorPage должен имплементировать интерфейс Initializable, также, в вашем FXML файле должна хранится информация про контроллер (класс, что имплементирует интерфейс Initializable) сделать это можно вот так:

loader.setController(ErrorPage);

после этого, в FXML файле дайте "имя" каждому элементу, который хотите изменить :

```
(Возле тэга элемента, в FXML файле напишите fx:id="label")
```

и уже потом в классе контроллера с помощью аннотации @FXML определите этот элемент

```
     @FXML
     private Label label
```

Comment: Спасибо за наводку с установлением контроллера :D Пару строк исправила и все заработало и без интерфейса Initializable

Comment: Вы правы, с 2 версии JavaFX имплементировать интрефейс Initializable совсем необязательно )

Answer (score 1):

Решение было на поверхности, но всё же, если у кого-то так же возникнут с этим проблемы

```
public void issueAnErrorMessage(String Message)

    {

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/sample/Error page.fxml"));
        try
        {
            loader.load();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ErrorPage controller = loader.getController();
        controller.SetMessage(Message);

        Parent root = loader.getRoot();
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.showAndWait();
    }
```

Больше ничего изменено не было